# Flutter: Shift in Android launch theme and normal theme image

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

In my flutter app, I provided LaunchTheme and NormalTheme for the android app

Both using the same xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But when the app opens, it shows the launch screen first with the image at center, but when it loads the normal theme, the image is shifted down a bit.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Android.
I've faced the same issue.

Based on the documentation for [flutter splash screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) NormalTheme makes sense and seems to work fine for avoiding the white screen before the app launches. But for some reason, it shifts the body tad bit lower which looks like bad UX.

further down in the documentation there's how to add a splash screen.

you could show the same thing as launch theme, even better you get a fade in of your root page by default.

add the splash screen tag inside the activity tag like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"...>
  .
  .
  .
 <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" 
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
</activity>
```

Remove the normal theme meta tag, it won't be neccessary.
It's too late to post this, but here it is.